# Sharing Static Content Between ASP.NET Core Apps

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, swashbuckle

I have customized a customized Swashbuckle UI using some custom HTML, CSS and image files in the following folders of my ASP.NET Core site:

```
wwwroot
  swagger
    ui
      images
        background.jpg
        favicon.ico
        logo_small.png
    index.html
    skin.css
```

How can I share these files in a separate class library so that multiple sites can use the same UI.

Comment: The files have to be in the wwwroot folder for Swashbuckle to puck them up.

Comment: Do you mean 'share' **for users** of your sites (e.g. download them only once from first site and then reuse from cache when visiting other sites) or **for you** (developer) for easy updating?

Comment: I am almost certain that swashbuckle has the resources embedded

Comment: Yes, Swashbuckle has the files embedded: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Ahoy/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi/project.json#L7-L8 You can do the same

Comment: The index.html file is a hard coded route, I need to override it https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Ahoy/blob/676988de4932b30a812594970cb1c13cd290e49a/test/WebSites/MultipleVersions/Swagger/SwaggerUiController.cs